# What are some standard generalisations of Noetherian rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, noetherian

Let $\textbf{CRing}$ be the category of commutative rings with $1$. Then, an immensely important subclass is that of the Noetherian rings, those rings which satisfy either of the equivalent conditions:

- every ascending chain of ideals terminates
- every ideal is finitely generated

What are some properties for rings which are similar to, but strictly weaker than, the Noetherian property, and also appear frequently in (research) mathematics?

For example, a property which satisfies the first two conditions might be that every ideal is countably generated. However, I doubt that it satisfies the third condition.

Comment: "the two conditions... the third condition". You only list two conditions.

Comment: For any cardinal $\kappa$, you can consider rings in which every ideal is generated by fewer than $\kappa$ elements; this is equivalent there being no strictly ascending $\kappa$-sequence of ideals in the ring. Noetherian corresponds to $\kappa=\aleph_0$, but you can ask for "countably generated", sure. Or you can ask that every finitely generated ideal be principal (Bezout rings).

Comment: Another nice generalization of Noetherian rings which comes up in algebraic geometry and commutative algebra is the class of [coherent rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_ring).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin (1) similar to Noetherian (2) strictly weaker than Noetherian (3) appear frequently in mathematics. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @AlexWertheim Interesting, thank you.

Comment: My confusion comes from the fact that the only statements you explicitly label "conditions" are the two highlighted statements, well known to be two of the three standard equivalent *conditions* for a ring to be noetherian. But apparently, by "conditions" you meant things mentioned elsewhere and not explicitly labeled "conditions".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see. But then, also apparently, you thought that I was talking about whether or not properties satisfy the equivalent conditions that every ascending chain of ideals terminates and every ideal is finitely generated. Considering that most properties don't even have ideals, this seems like a flawed interpretation. I think that there were contextual clues. But thank you for your feedback.